# Pause form submission for validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, validation, form-submit

I have some form, which uploads file in an iframe. I'd like to hold it's submission until I'll check if it's valid with ajax. How can I do this ? My code pauses the submission and returns validation result (currently just a dummy function which returns 'result': 'true') but then the 'submit' action is not performed. Also Is it normal that it takes ~2s to show response data after getting response 200 status ?

Here's my html:

```
<div id="message" style="background:black; width:400px; height:80px; display:none; color:white;">
</div>
<h1>Submit</h1>
<form action="{{upload_url}}" target="upload_target" method="POST" id="file_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% render_upload_data upload_data %}
    <table>{{ form }}</table>    
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" maxlength="64" name="myfileid" value="{{ myfileid }}" >
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="file_upload_submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>
```

Js:

```
$(function() {

    $('#file_upload_submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fileUploadForm = document.getElementById('file_upload_form');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/artifact/upload/check-form/',
            data: 'foo=bar',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                if(data['result'] == "true"){
                    $("#message").show();
                    $("#message").fadeIn(400).html('<span>'+data["message"]+'</span>');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#message").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            $("#message").hide();
                        });
                    }, 1500);
                     $('#file_upload_form').attr('target','upload_target').submit(function(){
                        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                        return false;
                    });
                }
                else{
                    $("#message").show();
                    $("#message").fadeIn(400).html('<span">'+data["message"]+'</span>');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#message").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            $("#message").hide();
                        });
                    }, 1500);                    
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return false;        
    });

});    

</script>
```

and link:
http://ntt.vipserv.org/artifact/

---

EDIT

With the code below I'm able to perform validation, then when it's result is positive form is submitted. Now if I hardcode target for form, my alert is not shown and I'm pretty sure that the upload is not performed (unfortunately list of uploads is refreshed each 8h sa I'll know if it worked in some time). If target is not specified, file is uploaded with redirect so the whole 'submit' event listener is ommitted.

```
<script>  
    $('#fake_upload_submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var fileUploadForm = document.getElementById('file_upload_form');
        fileUploadForm.addEventListener("submit", function() {
            alert("sent in iframe");
            fileUploadForm.target = 'upload_target';
        }, false);       

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/artifact/upload/check-form/',
            data: 'foo=bar',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                if(data['result'] == "true"){
                    $("#message").show();
                    $("#message").fadeIn(400).html('<span>'+data["message"]+'</span>');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#message").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            $("#message").hide();
                        });
                    }, 1500);

                    fileUploadForm.submit();

                }
                else{
                    $("#message").show();
                    $("#message").fadeIn(400).html('<span">Response false</span>');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#message").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            $("#message").hide();
                        });
                    }, 1500);                    
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return false;        
    });   
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="message" style="background:black; width:400px; height:80px; display:none; color:white;">
</div>
<h1>Submit</h1>
<form action="{{upload_url}}" method="POST" target="" id="file_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% render_upload_data upload_data %}
    <table>{{ form }}</table>    
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" maxlength="64" name="myfileid" value="{{ myfileid }}" >
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" style="display:none" id="true_upload_submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>    
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="fake_upload_submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

After the validation you register a new submit event handler, but there is nothing that submits the form, so you would have to click the button again to get it submitted.

You can just submit the form instead of adding a submit handler:

```
$('#file_upload_form').attr('target','upload_target').submit();
```

Comment: I have a .submit in line 21. Just added alert in there to check if it's processed. But it's not being shown :/

Comment: @mastodon: Adding a handler for the submit event doesn't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you might be over thinking the submission of the form, but I might also be reading this wrong. I may also not have all of the facts. Would it not be better to just submit the form via the ajax call and return the result of the submission (validation failed or succeeded)?

Pseudo code:

jQuery:

```
var formData = data;
ajax(formData);
```

Form Processing:

```
if(valid) {
  submit(formData);
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

I can provide real code if needed.

Comment: You can't post a file using AJAX.

Comment: I have the following situation. File from the form will be submitted to a remote server in iframe. The rest of the fields are going to be used to create an instance of object locally. So the local object will be created only when all the fields are properly filled.

Comment: haven't found anything about files there :/

Comment: You are missing the point. You can't upload a file to the server using an AJAX post. You have to post the actual form containing the upload field.

Answer (score 0):

It would likely be easiest for you (if possibly more annoying for your users) if you used synchronous XHR instead of asynchronous.

Alternatively, intercept the form submission using JavaScript and submit it using XHR iff the server-side validation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

How about avoiding the problem altogether, having a hidden submit button to submit the form and have a visible button that starts validation and if it's ok then it performs a click on the proper hidden submit button ?

Comment: it may be some solution, but currently the .submit action is somehow ommited so still my form won't be submitted.

Comment: when I said hidden I meant to set style="display:none" and not to set Visible="False" on the button if that is what you mean

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/292764/ tried that one also, but alert from submit is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

[Guffa is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205574/pause-form-submission-for-validation/4205751#4205751). I believe the following change will make the first script work. Change

```
                     $('#file_upload_form').attr('target','upload_target').submit(function(){
                        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                        return false;
                    });
```

to

```
                     $('#file_upload_form').attr('target','upload_target').submit();
```

It's your debugging that has broken the submission. If you want to keep the debugging, change the code to:

```
                     $('#file_upload_form').attr('target','upload_target').submit(function(){
                        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                        return true;
                    }).submit();
```

You must call `submit()` on its own to trigger the submission event. If the submit function returns `false`, it will not continue, so you must have it return `true` instead.

This is the third version of this question that you've posted. I agree with others that you may be addressing your problem in a way that is overcomplicated. This is a case where you may want to avoid JavaScript altogether and go for a straightforward HTML post. Is there a compelling reason why this is not an option?